# Convergence in law of the remedian

Tags: distributions, convergence, cumulative-distribution-function

I try to understand the theroem 2 of this article about the remedian
(https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3d64/5e60691838bf4699e79458d96930ba7bf24e.pdf)

I will try to phrase it more general so that you dont have to read the whole therorem necessarily.

The distribution function of the remedian is denoted as $J_k$. The theorem says that this converges to a distribution function $H_b$.

The authors show that $J_k$ are functions from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ for $k$ large enough. They also show that $J_k$ is a bounded and decreasing series, thus it converges to a value in $[0,1]$.

I dont really understand why the limit functions $H_b$ is a cdf. There is no formula given for it, so how can I proof the properties of a cdf for $H_b$, i.e right-continous, non-decreasing and the limits $x\rightarrow \infty$, $x\rightarrow -\infty$? Or does that follow from the fact that $J_k$ are functions from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$? Or why is that even needed?